# How do i animate with a big sprite in ios?

Tags: ios, animation, video

I have to make an animated infographic in iOS. Its consists of about 140 images all 900x700 large. Whats the best approach to do this? I tried CALayerwith indivual images, and also a spritesheet. But it just takes way too long to load and the playback is awful. I also have the animation in a video file, but it needs to be added to a view in a set frame and not be played in full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and play the animation video using [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can play it in a view with custom frame. You can refer the link for sample code too.

Comment: Good suggestion! I tried it and it does play, but no video appears. This is my code `player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"p6-cirkeldiagram_1" withExtension:@"mov"]];
            [player prepareToPlay];
           // [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
            [player.view setFrame: CGRectMake(46, 225, 675, 525)];  // player's frame must match parent's
            [self.view addSubview: player.view];
            [player play];
            [player setFullscreen:YES]; `

Comment: you say that it does play but no video appears ... Can you please elaborate ?

Also, did you find any related info from debug logs ?

Comment: nvm, it was a mov file, re-exporting it to m4v fixed it. Thanks!